# Excel VBA Search in folder and subfolders and returns multiple files

Tags: excel, string, vba, search, directory

I have to search and copy a number of files in a folder starting from an Excel list like:

```
8100 ' cell "A2"
8152 ' cell "A3"
8153 ' cell "A4"
```

in the source folders there are files named like this:

```
8153.pdf
100_8152.pdf
102_8153.pdf
8153 (2).pdf
```

How can I find these files and copy ALL the files that matches in a separate folder? The code returns only one file, but I need ALL the files matching the cell value. I need to extend my research in subfolders organized by years too (ie: "D:\myfolder\2015", "D:\myfolder\2016", etc.).
Thanks to user3598756, I'm now using this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cerca()
Dim T As Variant
Dim D As Variant

T = VBA.Format(VBA.Time, "hh.mm.ss")
D = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "yyyy.MM.dd")

Dim Source As String
Dim Dest As String
Dim Missed As String
Dim fileFound As String
Dim CodiceCS As Variant
Dim cell As Range

Source = "D:\myfolder\"
Dest = "D:\myfolder\research " & D & " " & T

If Dir(Dest, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir Dest '<--| create destination folder if not alerady there

With Worksheets("Cerca") '<-- reference your worksheet with pdf names
    For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- loop through its column "A" cells with "constant" (i.e. not resulting from formulas) values from row 2 down to last non empty one
        CodiceCS = VBA.Left((cell.Value), 4)
        fileFound = Dir(Source & "\" & CodiceCS & "\*" & cell.Value & "*.Pdf") '<-- look for a source folder file whose name contains the current cell value
        If fileFound <> "" Then '<-- if found...
            FileCopy Source & "\" & CodiceCS & "\" & fileFound, Dest & "\" & fileFound '<-- ...copy to destination folder
        Else '<--otherwise...
            Missed = Missed & cell.Value & vbCrLf '<--... update missing files list
        End If
    Next cell
End With

If Missed <> "" Then '<-- if there's any missing file
    Dim FF As Long
    FF = FreeFile

    Open (Dest & "\" & "MissingFiles.txt") For Output As #FF
    Write #FF, VBA.Left(Missed, Len(Missed) - 2)
    Close #FF
End If

MsgBox "OK"
Shell "explorer.exe " + Dest, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Should 8153 match to all files containing the value 8153?  i.e. 8153.pdf, 102_8153.pdf and 8153 (2).pdf.

Comment: If `filefound` is in both 2015 & 2016 folder do you rename the files when moved to the destination folder?

Comment: Yes, 8153 should match all files as you says; I don't need to rename files because the file is never located in both folders

Comment: The code in my answer should work - you could speed it up by putting an `Exit For` just after `FileFound = TRUE`.  If the file is never located in both folders you might as well stop looking after it's found.

Answer (score 0):

This code will place all the file names in the main folder and subfolders into an array.  It then looks through the array for matching values.

I've included an extra couple of lines which I've commented out - these are different options you could do within the code.

```
Public Sub cerca()

    Dim DT As String
    Dim Source As String
    Dim Dest As String
    Dim vFiles As Variant
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim FileFound As Boolean
    Dim FF As Long

    FF = FreeFile
    DT = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd hh.mm.ss")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Source = "D:\myfolder\"
    Dest = "D:\myfolder\research  " & DT

    If Dir(Dest, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir Dest

    'Get the full path name of all PDF files in the source folder and subfolders.
    vFiles = EnumerateFiles(Source, "pdf")

    With Worksheets("Cerca")
        'Look at each cell containing file names.
        For Each rCell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            FileFound = False 'Assume the file hasn't been found.
            'Check each value in the array of files.
            For Each vFile In vFiles
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                'Use this line if the file name in the sheet exactly match the file name in the array. '
                '8152 and 100_8152.pdf are not a match, 8152 and 8152.pdf are a match.                                                '
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                If rCell & ".pdf" = FileNameOnly(vFile) Then

                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                'Use this line if the file name in the sheet should appear in the file name in the array. '
                '8152 and 100_8152.pdf are a match, 1852 and 8152.pdf are a match.                        '
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                'If InStr(FileNameOnly(vFile), rCell.Value) > 0 Then

                    'If found copy the file over and indicate it was found.

                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    'This line will use the rcell value to name the file. '
                    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    oFSO.CopyFile vFile, Dest & "\" & rCell & ".pdf"

                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    'This line will not rename the file. '
                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    'oFSO.CopyFile vFile, Dest & "\" & FileNameOnly(vFile)
                    FileFound = True
                End If
            Next vFile

            'Any file names that aren't found are appended to the text file.
            If Not FileFound Then
                Open (Dest & "\" & "MissingFiles.txt") For Append As #FF ' creates the file if it doesn't exist
                Print #FF, rCell ' write information at the end of the text file
                Close #FF
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With
End Sub

Public Function EnumerateFiles(sDirectory As String, _
            Optional sFileSpec As String = "*", _
            Optional InclSubFolders As Boolean = True) As Variant

    EnumerateFiles = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec _
        ("CMD /C DIR """ & sDirectory & "*." & sFileSpec & """ " & _
        IIf(InclSubFolders, "/S ", "") & "/B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

End Function

Public Function FileNameOnly(ByVal FileNameAndPath As String) As String
    FileNameOnly = Mid(FileNameAndPath, InStrRev(FileNameAndPath, "\") + 1, Len(FileNameAndPath))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code is very slow: the cmd prompt runs for 5 minutes and then stops because of "out of memory" error. I tried a few optimization, but nothing works...